# Unable to execute Maven project using Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have created a Maven project in Jenkins. When I click on "build now", I am getting an error as below but I am able to run this project from the command prompt using `maven package`.

```
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f 
C:\Users\Administrator\.jenkins\workspace\maven\pom.xml mvn package
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Sources

channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Could you share the Job configuration, for further details to find out root cause.